Performing update and delete operations on mysql database records presented as a list of RadioButtons
How can i update and delete a database record using an angular web page when the record is presented and selected as a radio button in a child component and the update or delete button is in a parent component? I'll appreciate a code samples to support this. Clicking either of them will bring out bootstrap modals for updating and deleting. My problem is that if I select a partcular radio button for a city name and click update, it gets added as a new record rather than getting updated. The delete modal comes up but on clicking delete nothing happens. I believe the issue is about having a way to access each radio button properly as an object for execution not just the text. Some sample code are shown below...I'm particularly interested in doing the crud operations with the RadioButtons and I'll want the pages refreshed after each operations. My backend is springboot...
origin.ts
export interface Origin
{
id: number;

origin: string;

}
origin.component.html
<div><input type="radio"  name="origin" (change)="onSelectOrigin($event)" value={{origin.origin}}>{{origin.origin}}</div>

origin.component.ts
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Origin } from '../../origin';
import { OriginService } from '../../origin.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AnimationQueryMetadata } from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
selector: 'app-origin',
standalone: true,
imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
templateUrl: './origin.component.html',
styleUrl: './origin.component.css'
})
export class OriginComponent implements OnInit
{
public origins?: Origin[];
@Input() public origin: Origin | any;
@Output() public theorigin: EventEmitter;
@Output() public originSelect: EventEmitter;
constructor(private originService: OriginService) {
this.theorigin = new EventEmitter<Origin>();

this.originSelect = new EventEmitter<Origin>();

}
ngOnInit(): void {
this.getOrigins();

}
public getOrigins(): void {
this.originService.getOrigins().subscribe(



  (response: Origin[]) => {



    this.origins = response;

  },

  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

    alert(error.message)

  }

);

}
public onOpenModal(event: any): void
{
 this.theorigin.emit(this.origin);

}
public onSelectOrigin(event: any): void
{
this.theorigin.emit(event.target.value);

}
}
Parent component - app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { Origin } from './origin';
import { OriginService } from './origin.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OriginComponent } from './locations/origin/origin.component';
import { DestinationComponent } from './locations/destination/destination.component';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
standalone: true,
imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, OriginComponent, DestinationComponent, FormsModule],
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
title = 'packagedeliveryrouting';
originName?: Origin;
public editOrigin?: Origin;
public deleteOrigin?: Origin;
public origComp!: OriginComponent;
constructor(private originService: OriginService) {
}
ngOnInit(): void {
this.origComp = new OriginComponent(this.originService);

}
public onUpdateOrigin(origin: Origin): void
{
//document.getElementById("theclose")?.click();

this.editOrigin = origin;

this.originService.updateOrigin(this.editOrigin).subscribe(



   (response: Origin) => {

     console.log(response);

     this.origComp.getOrigins();

   },

   (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

      alert(error.message);

   }

 );

}
public onDeleteOrigin(originId: number | any): void
{
//document.getElementById("theclose")?.click();



this.originService.deleteOrigin(originId).subscribe(



   (response: void) => {

     console.log(response);

     this.origComp.getOrigins();

   },

   (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

      alert(error.message);

   }

 );

}
public onOpenModal(origin: Origin | any, mode: string): void
{
 const container = document.getElementById('main-container');

 const button = document.createElement('button');

 button.type = 'button';

 button.style.display = 'none';

 button.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'modal');

 this.originName = origin;

 console.log(`THEMODE ${this.originName}`);



  //this.editOrigin = orig;

  if(mode === 'edit')

  {

    this.editOrigin = origin;

    console.log(`see ${this.editOrigin}`);

    button.setAttribute('data-bs-target', '#myModal');

  }



  if(mode === 'delete')

  {

      this.deleteOrigin = origin;

      console.log(`see ${this.onDeleteOrigin}`);

      button.setAttribute('data-bs-target', '#myModalDel');

  }

   

 

  container?.appendChild(button);

  button.click();

}
public onSelectOrigin(origin: Origin | any): void
{
this.originName = origin

//console.log(`origin ${this.originName}`)

}
}
Parent component - app.component.html
<div class="col-md-12">

  <div style="border: 1px solid #000;">

  <h1>GeoByte Inc</h1>

</div>

</div>

<nav>

  <a href="">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <a href="">About us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <a href="">Register</a>

</nav>

<div id="location"><h2>Locations</h2></div>

<div class="col-md-3">

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; border: 1px solid #000"></div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3">

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; border: 1px solid #000">

      <h4>Origin</h4>

      <app-origin (theorigin)="onSelectOrigin($event)"></app-origin>

      <button type="button" (click)="onOpenModal(editOrigin, 'edit')" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

      <button type="button" (click)="onOpenModal(deleteOrigin, 'delete')" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>

      <!--<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Click</button>-->

     

  </div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3">

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; border: 1px solid #000">

    <h4>Destination</h4>

     <app-destination></app-destination>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>

     

</div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3">

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; border: 1px solid #000"></div>

</div>

{{originName}}
<div class="modal-content">

  <div class="modal-header">

    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>

    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    Content for the dialog / modal goes here.

    {{originName}}

    <form #editForm="ngForm">

      <div class="form-group">

        <label for="name">Name</label>

        <input type="text" ngModel="{{editOrigin?.origin}}" name="origin" class="form-control" id="origin" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="origin" required>

        <input type="hidden" ngModel="{{editOrigin?.id}}" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="id" required>

      </div>

     



   

   <div class="modal-footer">

    <a href="#" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn" id="theclose">Close</a>

    <a href="#" (click)="onUpdateOrigin(editForm.value)" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

  </div>

</form>

</div>

<div class="modal-content">

  <div class="modal-header">

   

    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>

    <h5 class="modal-title" >Delete Employee</h5>

  </div>

 

  <div class="modal-body">

      <p>Are you sure you want to delete origin {{deleteOrigin?.origin}}?</p>

      <div class="modal-footer">

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">No</button>

         <button (click)="onDeleteOrigin(deleteOrigin?.id)" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>

      </div>

  </div><!--modal-body ends here-->

</div><!--modal-content ends here-->

I'm appreciate someone's assistance
Olakunle Oni
My problem is that if I select a partcular radio button for a city name and click update, it gets added as a new record rather than getting updated. The delete modal comes up but on clicking delete nothing happens.
